# Lower bound on the probability of getting the same event twice in two i.i.d. draws.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume I perform two independent draws from the same probability distribution $X_1,X_2 \sim F_X$, where $F_X$ is a discrete probability mass function. My problem is that $F_X$ is very difficult or impossible to compute exactly. Can I still get a lower bound on the probability $\mathsf P(X_1=X_2)$?

I have the following idea:

The probability of getting the same outcome twice should be minimal if $F_X$ is the uniform distribution. If $F_X$ was not uniform, there would be an event which is more probable than others in both random draws, which should increase the probability of getting the same event twice.

That would mean $\frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert}$ should be a lower bound on the probability of getting the same event twice right?

Am I correct and if so, how can I formally prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometric approach. Suppose that your discrete probability distribution $F$ can be described by $n$ outcomes of probability $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. Then,

$$P(a=b)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2.$$

So the best lower bound you can get is

$$\min_{p\in \Delta_n} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2$$

where $\Delta_n=\{(p_1,\ldots,p_n) : p_i\ge 0, \sum_i p_i=1\}$. Now we are minimizing a convex function on a polytope, so we can use the method of Lagrange multipliers to show that the minimizer is actually the uniform distribution.